# pipe still not found in component using shared module

Tags: angular

I have a pipe I want to use in a component in a module.

At the module page level. I am able to use it.

But at the component level that us under this module, I cannot.

```
//shared module for the pipe
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DefaultPipe],
  exports: [DefaultPipe]
})
export class DefaultPipeModule{}

//shared module with the component and pipe
@NgModule({
  imports: [DefaultPipeModule],
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  exports: [LoginComponent]
})
export class FooModule {}


//main page module
@NgModule({
  imports: [FooModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class MainModule{}
```

At the main module, I am able to use the pipe in the template.

But not at the LoginComponent.

```
The pipe 'defaulttestpipe' could not be found in the 'LoginComponent' component
```

I have basically tried everything.

First I tried to import the pipe directly.

Then as a shared module.

Now as a shared module with the pipe module and component.

And several other methods including directly using providers on the component.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The way you're doing it should work. Are you sure the name "defaulttestpipe" matches the name in the @Pipe decorator verbatim?

Comment: yes. The name is correct. as I mentioned it works in the main module, but not in the component within that module. the logincomponent is rendered, but the pipe is still not found.

Comment: @dormant Could you share a stackblitz with the issue replicated?

Comment: It's very weird. At this point I'll probably test this within a clean project.  It works at  the module I import it, the main module template, but not within the component template. The main  module is a page has a module, but the component does not. The component is definitely rendered.

Comment: Don't know exactly why. But after creating a new component with a different name to replace the current one. It now works. I suspect it could be a name conflict somewhere in my existing project. It's just one of those things...

Comment: Maybe It's because you have declared `LoginComponent` in more than on module. Check to define `LoginComponent` only inside `FooModule`.